# splitting a column into individual words then filter results

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I have a column where I would like to break it into individual words for an "auto suggest" on text box.  I was able to accomplish this thanks to this article: 
http://discourse.bigdinosaur.org/t/sql-and-database-splitting-a-column-into-individual-words/709/45

However, the results have characters that I don't want like "/' , etc.
I have a database function that I use when I want to filter out characters, but I cannot figure out how to merge the 2 and get it to work.

```
Here's the splitting code:
;WITH for_tally (spc_loc) AS
    (SELECT 1 AS spc_loc
    UNION ALL
    SELECT spc_loc + 1 from for_tally WHERE spc_loc < 65
) 
SELECT spc_loc into #tally from for_tally OPTION(MAXRECURSION 65)

select substring(name, spc_loc, charindex(' ', name + ' ', spc_loc) - spc_loc) as word
  into #temptable
  from #tally, products
 where spc_loc <= convert(int, len(name))
   and substring(' ' + name, spc_loc, 1) = ' '
```

Then, here's how I view the table:

```
select distinct word from #temptable order by word
```

Then here's how I call the database function in other queries:

```
SELECT * INTO #Keywords FROM dbo.SplitStringPattern(@Keywords, '[abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789-]')
```

Where @Keywords is the string to filter.

I've tried all I can think of, to filter the first query by the dbo.SplitStringPattern function

ie:

```
select substring(dbo.SplitStringPattern(name, '[abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789-]'), spc_loc, charindex(' ', name + ' ', spc_loc) - spc_loc) as word
  into #temptable
  from #tally, products
 where spc_loc <= convert(int, len(name))
   and substring(' ' + name, spc_loc, 1) = ' '
```

But I get "Cannot find either column "dbo" or the user-defined function or aggregate "dbo.SplitStringPattern", or the name is ambiguous."

I need this to be optimized as this query needs to return results very quick.

Or, if there's a better way of doing this, I'm open to suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Create a T-SQL Function to filter out the unwanted characters before your "database function" is called. The following web page links should help.

- [MSDN Create Function (Transact-SQL)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186755.aspx)
- [How to remove special characters from a string in MS SQL Server (T-SQL)](http://www.source-code.biz/snippets/mssql/1.htm)

Comment: isn't that what the dbo.SplitStringPattern(name, '[abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789-]') is? If not, how does that differ and can you please explain it?